# Android TV: how to partially hide header fragment, hide text and show only icons like netflix tv app

Tags: android, leanback

I am using leanback and I want to make headers like Netflix has in its Android tv app like below.

[image]

[image]

when header fragment is opened it shows both text along with icon(first image) and when header is closed they only show icon and highlight it. (second image).

In my app I'm able to develop the customize header with text and icons but I want to show this half-way hiding like Netflix is doing. Is there any way to achieve this functionality. Kindly suggest.

Comment: hey did you find the solution for it? Also, I want to ask you how did you implement the preview background like Netflix with focus maintained? I am able to do the former part but not sure how to do the latter i.e. maintaining focus.

Comment: I did not find the solution with leanback but I had made it using other Recycler view.  I can explain if you want. Please show me what is your required layout then I will suggest.

Comment: it is same like netflix. On left side Side bar navigation should be shown always with icons visible and when hovered over/in-focus it should expand showing menu names as well. On right side, content/rows should start from below the background preview.

Comment: For right side the way I have managed to add background preview is by adding a fragment and adding BrowseSupportFragment over it. But i had to override/increase rows top margin to make rows start from below the preview but this pushed menu on left also to down and doesn’t look good. Please suggest approaches, we can chat over other medium as well if you like. It’s important thanks.

Comment: I don't think I would be able help you achieve this fully, but yeah lets discuss I will be happy to help.

Comment: this is the solution https://github.com/Arpit0492/TVNavigationMenu

Comment: I am glad you finally found it. Thank you for sharing it with me. I will explore it.